# Std class vs Anonymous class in PHP7+

Tags: php, performance, stdclass

Std class is the generic class in PHP. It appeared in PHP 5 and is the generic class used (for example, when converting a value to Object, it create [a new instance of StdClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object#language.types.object.casting).)

An anonymous class is a one-off object, anonymous (obviously), and introduced in PHP 7.

So what's the difference between them? Is there still a reason to use StdClass over Anonymous class in PHP 7 and upper ?

Comment: In which use case?

Comment: Well, actually, that's my question. In which case should I use StdClass over Anonymous Class?

Comment: `stdClass` is obviously not anonymous. I don't think the two are even comparable concepts. `stdClass` differs to any other named class in the same way it differs from any anonymous class. It's a built-in PHP class and PHP uses it in cases where e.g. it needs to cast something to an object. An anonymous class like a named class has a specific implementation and instances of that class conform to that implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems even in PHP 8 if you cast an array to object you still get `stdClass`:

```
$test = (object) [];
var_dump($test); //output: object(stdClass)#1 (0) {}

$test = new class{};
var_dump($test); //output: object(class@anonymous)#1 (0) {}
```

So it is safe to assume it is still the generic class in php 7 and 8.

One difference is when you want to declare some method or even the `__construct` method for the object:

```
$object = new class('value') {

    private $val;
    
    public function __construct($val){
        $this->val = $val;
    }
    
    public function getVal(){
        return $this->val;
    }
};
```

Above code is obviously more readable regards to object orianted concepts like encapsulation.

But if you need to create an empty object I would suggest to use `stdClass` ( or `(object)[]` to type less) over anonymous class since it was intended to derive fully modelled objects.

If you want to have some public properties in the object, still `(object)[]` would be a more readable way to go:

```
$object = (object) [
    "firstName" => "John",
    "lastName" => "Doe"
];

$object = new class{};
$object->firstName = "John";
$object->lastName = "Doe";
```

If you need some methods for the object, anonymous class would be a better option.

If you want to have private properties, again anonymous class is the way to go.

If you want your object to implement some interface then definitely go with anonymous class:

```
interface Logger {
    public function log(string $msg);
}

class Application {
    private $logger;

    public function getLogger(): Logger {
         return $this->logger;
    }

    public function setLogger(Logger $logger) {
         $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}

$app = new Application;
$app->setLogger(new class implements Logger {
    public function log(string $msg) {
        echo $msg;
    }
});
```

If you want your object to extend some class then again anonymous class is the way to go:

```
$object = new class extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        /** ... **/
    }
};

$object->start();
```